# Add dash '-' on evry four character input in Textbox for store Credit Card Information in Windows phone 8.1 c#

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing bank application , I have to store Credit Card information for that

1. Input card number from user
2. on every four character dash `'-'` will be added on that text box

e.g `1234-1234-1234-1234`

I have try `KeyDown` and `TextChanged`, but didn't get answer.
key down event

```
txtcardNumber.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
            string temp = string.Empty;
            if (txtcardNumber.Text.Length == 4)
            {
                temp = txtcardNumber.Text;

                txtcardNumber.Text += '-';
                txtcardNumber.UpdateLayout();



            }
            else if (txtcardNumber.Text.Length == 9)
            {
                txtcardNumber.Text = txtcardNumber.Text + "-";
            }
            else if (txtcardNumber.Text.Length == 14)
            {
                txtcardNumber.Text = txtcardNumber.Text + "-";
            }
```

when it add '-' cursor automatically goes at the start , I don't know why

Comment: That's a job for a MaskedTextBox :)

Comment: How about masked `textboxes` ? i don't Know whether it is applicable in your case

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: how can we use MaskedTextBoxes  in windows phone 8.1 phone (RT) application ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`MaskedTextBoxes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for such scenarios. and you can set the mask as follows:

```
mskCardBox.Mask = "0000-0000-0000-0000";
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps you....

Dont wait till dash come after 4 digits. 
Take a textbox double click it and write the below code and make that textbox autopostback=true.

write all 16 digits at a time and click tab or enter , dash will come automatically by splitting 4 digits each.

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cardno = TextBox1.Text;
    var list = Enumerable
        .Range(0, cardno.Length / 4)
        .Select(i => cardno.Substring(i * 4, 4))
        .ToList();
    var resl = string.Join("-", list);
    TextBox1.Text = resl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found simple solution

```
               var insertText = "-";
               var selectionIndex = creditcard.SelectionStart;
               creditcard.Text = creditcard.Text.Insert(selectionIndex, insertText);
               creditcard.SelectionStart = selectionIndex + insertText.Length;
```